# Angular shows 2 views after change a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have initialization app.js script where outlined possible states of my app

The problem is when I open company state and then open news or events state, it doesn't replace '' view from another state but just combine it..

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'search': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
                  controller: 'categoryCtrl'
                },
                'footer': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'
                }   
            }
        })
        .state('company', {
            url: '/company/:id',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/company.html',
                    controller: 'companyCtrl'
                },
                'about@company': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company-tabs/about.html'
                },
                'testimonials@company': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company-tabs/testimonials.html'
                },
                'questions@company': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company-tabs/questions.html'
                },
                'contacts@company': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company-tabs/contacts.html',
                  controller: 'yaMapCtrl'
                },
                'form@company': {
                  templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
                  controller: 'formCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('news', {
            url: '/news',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/news.html',
                    controller: 'newsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
    .state('events', {
        url: '/events',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'views/events.html',
                controller: 'eventsCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
})
```

I can see both '' views from company and events states together, whereas I have only one call of a view in my main html page

```
    <div ui-view=""></div>
```

Please help